# List and enable/disable Compiz plugins on command line

Tags: compiz

How can I see the default set of Compiz plugins and add or remove plugins from the set using the command line interface?

Is there a config file I can edit for system-wide configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From 14.04

## List active compiz plugins

Run `dconf dump /org/compiz/profiles/unity/ | grep active-plugins` in a Terminal.  This will give you someting like

```
active-plugins=['core', 'composite', 'opengl', 'wall', 'resize', 'vpswitch', 'compiztoolbox', 'move', 'snap', 'grid', 'imgpng', 'commands', 'unitymtgrabhandles', 'mousepoll', 'place', 'copytex', 'regex', 'session', 'animation', 'fade', 'expo', 'workarounds', 'ezoom', 'scale', 'unityshell']
```

## Configure settings per user

See answer https://askubuntu.com/a/320677/10475

## System-wide configuration

Normally you could make system-wide settings with [vendor overrides in gsettings](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GSettings.html#id-1.4.19.2.9.21). As it is [not possible to write a schema override file that includes a DConf path](http://blog.chapus.net/more-gnome-unity-system-defaults/) (see also [#1281580](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glib2.0/+bug/1281580)) you have to [set the settings in dconf directly](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/dconf/SystemAdministrators):

**Step 1**: Create a file `user` in `/etc/dconf/profile/` with this content:

```
user-db:user  
system-db:compiz
```

**Step 2**: Create a folder `compiz.d` in `/etc/dconf/db/`

**Step 3**:
Create the file `00_default_plugins` in `/etc/dconf/db/compiz.d/` and put `_your list of plugins_` inside (run `dconf dump /org/compiz/profiles/unity/ | grep active-plugins`
 to get a list of your actually activated plugins).

Example:

```
[org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core]  
active-plugins=['core', 'composite', 'opengl', 'move', 'vpswitch', 'copytex', 'grid', 'commands', 'snap', 'compiztoolbox', 'mousepoll', 'place', 'resize', 'imgpng', 'session', 'wall', 'regex',  'unitymtgrabhandles', 'animation', 'winrules', 'fade', 'workarounds', 'expo', 'scale', 'ezoom', 'unityshell']
```

**Step 4**:
Make this setting mandatory. Create a folder `locks` in `/etc/dconf/db/compiz.d/` and put a file named `00_compiz_active_plugins` with this content inside:

`/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/active-plugins`

**Step 5**: Run `sudo dconf update` in a terminal to compile.

---

Now you can open a guest session and check if the setting is applied.

**NB**: You can name `system-db` the way you like but keep in mind that the folder `compiz.d` in my example has to be named the same as your `system-db` with a `.d` appended.

**Credits**:
 https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/dconf/SystemAdministrators
 http://blog.chapus.net/more-gnome-unity-system-defaults/

Answer (score 5):

At least in 11.04 & 11.10 this will give you a list of the enabled plugins inside of brackets. []

```
 gconftool-2 --get  /apps/compiz-1/general/screen0/options/active_plugins
```

you can take that list, add to or subtract and then set with this, using " around the brackets "[]"

```
gconftool-2 --set --type=list --list-type=string /apps/compiz-1/general/screen0/options/active_plugins "[list,goes,in,here]"
```

[image]

Comment: Remember that gconf does no conflict resolution so keep that in mind when adding plugins where a possibility exists

Comment: Before I add, I need to know the available plugins. How to find those? (I know the name that shows in CCSM, but I doubt it will help in the command line) And does it set system-wide?

Comment: `$  gconftool-2 --get  /apps/compiz-1/general/screen0/options/active_plugins
No value set for '/apps/compiz-1/general/screen0/options/active_plugins'`

Comment: It possibly could be in another 'location', what are you running? If you open gconf-editor you can take a look to see where. (Atm I only have 11.10 & 12.04 install which use the above posted 'location'

Comment: Running Oneiric. Maybe there's a typo in what you posted?

Comment: No typo - edited in a screenshot of gconf-editor but needs to be reviewed - ex. from here in next comment of the get command, suggest you browse thhru gconf-editor

Comment: ~$ gconftool-2 --get /apps/compiz-1/general/screen0/options/active_plugins [core,composite,opengl,compiztoolbox,decor,vpswitch,mousepoll,wall,text,place,move,resize,gnomecompat,imgpng,regex,animation,fade,expo,scale,scaleaddon,unityshell]

Comment: Not used to this format - edited the screen into your post instead of mine - sorry about that

Comment: I've installed Compiz in LXDE, if it makes any difference.

Comment: System completely freezes after doing the `gconftool-2 --set` on Raring.