# What determines what is present in gsettings?

Tags: xubuntu, gsettings

I'm on Xubuntu 13.10. I ran this command:

```
$ gsettings list-recursively > ~/Desktop/gset.txt
```

I see a lot of stuff unrelated to Xubuntu. For example:

```
com.canonical.Unity.Lenses always-search ['applications.scope', 'music.scope', 'videos.scope', 'files.scope']
com.canonical.Unity.Lenses disabled-scopes @as []
com.canonical.Unity.Lenses hidden-scopes @as []
com.canonical.Unity.Lenses home-lens-default-view ['applications.scope', 'files.scope']
com.canonical.Unity.Lenses home-lens-priority ['files.scope', 'music.scope']
com.canonical.Unity.Lenses locked-scopes @as []
com.canonical.Unity.Lenses remote-content-search 'all'
```

Why are these entries present? Is it because there is a "default" gsettings that is packaged along with all the official flavors derived from Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are right, Some "default" Gsettings  are packaged along with all the official flavors derived from Ubuntu. In this case, it is packaged with a Unity lib.

Example from my Lubuntu 14.04, no Unity desktop installed:

1. Check for their schema file

   ```
   $ grep -r com.canonical.Unity.Lenses /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
   Binary file /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/gschemas.compiled matches
   /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.Unity.Lenses.gschema.xml:  <schema path="/com/canonical/unity/lenses/" id="com.canonical.Unity.Lenses" gettext-domain="libunity">
   ```

   `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.Unity.Lenses.gschema.xml` is there.
2. Check which package installed it:

   ```
   $ dpkg -S /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.Unity.Lenses.gschema.xml
   libunity9:amd64: /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.Unity.Lenses.gschema.xml
   ```

   So it was `libunity9`
3. May be, at least one application of these was installed:

   ```
   $ apt-cache rdepends libunity9
   libunity9
   Reverse Depends:
     thunderbird-gnome-support
     nautilus
     empathy
     libunity9:i386
     libunity9:i386
     libunity-protocol-private0:i386
     libunity-dev:i386
     xchat-indicator
     wallch
     unity-scope-onlinemusic
     unity-scope-mediascanner
     unity-china-video-scope
     unity-china-music-scope
     psensor
     liferea
     libunity-tools
     claws-mail-multi-notifier
     xchat-gnome-indicator
     unity-webapps-service
     unity-webapps-qml
     unity-scope-video-remote
     unity-scope-musicstores
     unity-scope-home
     unity-lens-video
     unity-lens-music
     unity-lens-friends
     unity-lens-files
     unity-lens-applications
     thunderbird-gnome-support
     telepathy-indicator
     shotwell
     nautilus
     libunity-protocol-private0
     libunity-dev
     libunity-dev
     libbrasero-media3-1
     gir1.2-unity-5.0
     evolution-indicator
     empathy
     deja-dup
   ```

For better understanding Gsettings related files, see [Shouldn't dconf-editor and gsettings access the same database?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/416556/shouldnt-dconf-editor-and-gsettings-access-the-same-database)

BTW, Some keys may not have a related schema, like the case of some Compiz settings (in Unity or Gnome session, Lubuntu session uses `ini` file). Even to way to accesses those keys: Dconf Path should be specified within gsettings command, see example [How to use gsettings when there is no schema listed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320674/how-to-use-gsettings-when-there-is-no-schema-listed)