# dconf database how to remove duplicate & triplicates?

Tags: command-line, database, dconf, gsettings

My `gsettings` database has many entries that are duplicated or triplicated. Some are "normal" single entries.

```
$ gsettings --schemadir /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas list-recursively | grep button-power
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power 'interactive'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power 'interactive'

$ gsettings list-recursively | grep sudoku-difficulty
org.gnome.sudoku print-multiple-sudoku-difficulty 'easy'

$ gsettings list-recursively | grep print-wrap-mode
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.print print-wrap-mode 'word'
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.print print-wrap-mode 'word'
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.print print-wrap-mode 'word'
```

---

### `dconf dump` and `dconf load` are not effective

The utility `dconf dump` doesn't show duplicate entries:

```
$ dconf dump /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/
[/]
idle-dim=false
lid-close-battery-action='nothing'
critical-battery-action='shutdown'
lid-close-ac-action='nothing'
```

Running `dconf dump` of single entries to file and import same file using `dconf load` doesn't get rid of duplicate entries:

```
$ gsettings list-recursively | grep lid-close-battery
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action 'nothing'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action 'nothing'

$ dconf dump /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/ > dconf-lid-battery.txt

$ dconf load /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/ < dconf-lid-battery.txt

$ gsettings list-recursively | grep lid-close-battery
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action 'nothing'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action 'nothing'
```

---

### Might be a bug?

Appears to be a bug:

- [gsettings list-recursively does not output paths while schema/key/value are path-dependent](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=723003#c12)

Based on bug reports it could be these three areas:

```
$ gsettings get org.freedesktop.ibus.general dconf-preserve-name-prefixes
['/desktop/ibus/engine/pinyin', '/desktop/ibus/engine/bopomofo', '/desktop/ibus/engine/hangul']
```

---

### Replies to comments

Here are file and directory names of `/etc/dconf`:

```
$ tree /etc/dconf/
/etc/dconf/
├── db
│   ├── ibus
│   └── ibus.d
│       └── 00-upstream-settings
└── profile
    └── ibus

3 directories, 3 files
```

Two of three files are dated from 2016 (Ubuntu 16.04 development time):

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3163 Oct  1 16:51 /etc/dconf/db/ibus
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1978 Jan 19  2016 00-upstream-settings
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   28 Jan 19  2016 /etc/dconf/profile/ibus
```

Comment: if you remove an entry does that remove both? If not you could create a sorted list for gsettings list-recursively and move the dupes to a 2nd file and use that file to a remove.

Comment: @Rinzwind I've googled for an hour and still haven't figured out how to delete a `gsettings` / dconf database entry. Do you have a link to such a function?

Comment: It is `gsettings reset <key-path>` ;-) oh and I think I might have found your problem: you probably have 2 schema definitions.

Comment: @Rinzwind Unfortunately `reset` simply resets to installation default. It doesn't delete or remove the key-pair. After running for `lid-close-battery-action` above it changed the key from `nothing` to `suspend`. I will search for how I might have 2 or 3 schemas setup though.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix , first time to see such gsettings behavior. (1)Check `/etc/dconf/profile/` contents for active databases. (2)Use DBus monitor or d-feet to monitor replies dconf daemon while a gsettings query (if duplication exists in data passed). (3) dconf dump to backup user settings, logout, switch to console, login root (or superuser with sudo), *move* dconf user-db & system-db if there one  to backup them also `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/gschemas.compiled`, run `glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas` to compile new schema, logout then login through GUI & dconf load settings

Comment: The process in (3) is just to recreate dconf user-db from scratch. You may try create new  user to check . If (2) showing no duplicate in data, then it could be a bug in gsettings itself (dconf is out of the problem).

Comment: @user.dz Thanks for looking at my problem. I've updated answer with suggestion (1). It appears to be a skeleton and other databases need to be checked?

Comment: Could you share content of `/etc/dconf/profile/ibus` there you find the active dconf databases. My answer here https://askubuntu.com/a/417330/26246 have an example. See if you can go through option (3)

Comment: @user.dz There are two entries from `$ cat /etc/dconf/profile/ibus` first: `user-db:user` and second: `system-db:ibus`

Comment: So your user-db is `~/.config/dconf/user` and system-db is `/etc/dconf/db/ibus` for option (3)

Comment: @user.dz Your answer doesn't contain an "option (3)" There are two sections. In the second section there are number points 1 & 2 but no 3. In the second section there are bullet points and the third bullet point reads **Schema Files: Relation between schema id & schema path (.gschema.xml)** Is the Schema analysis what you mean by "option (3)"?

Comment: Excuse me that I wasn't clear. I meant (3)  of my comment here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090244/dconf-database-how-to-remove-duplicate-triplicates?noredirect=1#comment2009577_1090244 to create DB from scratch.

Comment: @user.dz Ahh *(light goes on)* now I get it. Sorry for being a bit daft. I'm in the middle of my first Pyhton project with tkinter resizable canvas, grids, x-scrollbars, y-scrollbars, etc. It's my first exposure transitioning from CLI & procedural bash language to GUI and OOPS so my brain is all mushy :( I will recreate DB from scratch and report back when I get a break from this inaugural Python project (if I'm still sane).

Comment: @user.dz This might be the cause: `gsettings get org.freedesktop.ibus.general dconf-preserve-name-prefixes` returns three sets: `['/desktop/ibus/engine/pinyin', '/desktop/ibus/engine/bopomofo', '/desktop/ibus/engine/hangul']` and I found references to prefixes in a closed Red Hat bug report today.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I have seen similar case to this but it wasn't same, I couldn't get a full grasp of it. It was with Compiz settings: that has separate dconf path for each profile but same gsettings id. gsettings query requires using both id & path. Good, I could find that post: https://askubuntu.com/q/320674/26246 . It is called a *"relocatable schema"*.