# Unity profile without window decorations or launchpad

Tags: unity, gnome, launcher, compiz

From one day to another (probably after an automatic update), when I log in to my profile, I do not see window decoration or the start menu. If I use another user, everything works fine. I had this problem before, so I know it is unity and compiz related. Back then, I solved it by moving away the `compizconfig` directory, but this does not do the trick this time, although it seems to be a profile-related issue.

The error message reads:

> **Sorry, Ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal error.**
>
> If you notice further problems, try restarting the computer.
>
> ExecutablePath `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/unity/compiz-config-profile-setter`
>
> Package `unity 7.4.5+16.04.20190312-0ubuntu1`
>
> ProblemType: Crash
>
> Title: compiz-config-profile-setter crashed with SIGSEGV in cssObjectGetInterface_()
>
> .tmp.unity_support_test.0
>
> ApportVersion: 2.20.1-ubuntu2.21
>
> CompizPlugins: No value set for '/apps/compiz-1/general/screen0/options/active_plugins'
>
> [...]

This error message appears only sometimes, the launchpad is never around though.

**How do I fix my broken profile with minimal effort?**

### References

- [Desktop with no 'sidebars' and cannot get out unless switch off computer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012750/desktop-with-no-sidebars-and-cannot-get-out-unless-switch-off-computer) describes exactly my problem, but was closed off as being duplicate (to the following two questions)
- [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears) describes a different problem
- [2/15/18 compiz update broke unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1006621/2-15-18-compiz-update-broke-unity) did *not* solve my issue
- [List and enable/disable Compiz plugins on command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74313/list-and-enable-disable-compiz-plugins-on-command-line) helped me to list all plugins, but what do I do next?
- [ubuntu 13.10 no launcher and no dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/376882/ubuntu-13-10-no-launcher-and-no-dash-appears) is for an older version
- [Ubuntu 16.04 - Unity doesn't load - no Launcher or Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/962497/ubuntu-16-04-unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-or-dash-appears) no accepted answer
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1758009 original source